# PHP JQuery Ajax Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function createUser(username, password) {

            $.post('/php/Create_User.php', { username: username, password : password},

                function(returnedData){

                    alert(returnedData);

                }).fail(function(error){

                alert(error.message);
            });

        }
    </script>
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
 <form onsubmit="createUser(this.username.value, this.password.value)" method="post">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Whenever I submit the form, the function gets called but it keeps going into the .fail block but the error message just says "undefined". I do not know how to print out errors or find out why my post is not returning data from my CreateUser page.

Comment: Are you sure error has a property called message?

Comment: @PatoSalazar no, I thought error was an object that comes back from the response and I saw other articles that had error.message being used. I tried just using error and printing it out just prints the word "object" so I assumed it has a property called message and gave it a shot. I am not sure how to view the error from the response.

Comment: @Nick can you console.log the error so that it can easily identity

Comment: @RaheelAslam where does console.log print out to? How can I view the error? Also I don't know how to get the error to print out.

Comment: @Nick you can console.log(returnedData) and console.log(error) and share the output of both.

Comment: `.fail()` has three parameters; the second is the text of the error message. Try using this: `.fail(function(xhr, error) { alert(error); });`

Comment: @Nick all i get is the word "error" in the alert.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible if you used the code exactly as I typed it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use jQuery `.post()`... Stop using the inline `onsubmit` attribute. Use a submit event handler where you can [prevent the normal submit behavior](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Then if you still have an error, console.log what is returned to determine the nature of the issue.

```js
$("form").on("submit",function(e){  // <-- Look closely here
  e.preventDefault();               //     And here.
  
  var username = $(this).find("[name='username']").val();
  var password = $(this).find("[name='password']").val();
  console.log(username+" "+password);
  
  $.post('/php/Create_User.php', { username: username, password : password})
    .done(function(returnedData){ 
      console.log(returnedData);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(error);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The request in this snippet **obviously** can't work here...

Comment: When I check logs, nothing gets printed out but it says "Navigated to" and then my server url with username and password parameters in there but no data response.

Comment: That's because the form was submitted by the "normal behavior" of the `<form>` element... Not by `.post()`. Look for [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: If you still hava a "Navigated to"... The normal submit is not prevented and the page reloaded. I added a "look closely" in the code posted in my answer. ;)

Comment: Doesnt the preventDefault stop that from happening? I copied your code and I still get the `Navigated to` message

Comment: Did you also remove the inline `onclick=...` ? And is there a `e` between parenthesis? The `.on()` method provides the event itself as the first argument of the callback...

Comment: Yes I have the same code the you have and I removed the on submit inline from my form.

Comment: And you still see a "Navigated to" ?? Ok, refresh that page using [ctrl]+[F5] (refresh without cache). I guess that code is in an external .js file...

Comment: @Nick The other possibility is that you have the JavaScript code before your form element. Make sure it is _after_ the form element, or wrap it in a [`$(document).ready` callback](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) so it won't run until the HTML has been parsed.

Comment: @Nathan wow that was it, I thought `/script` is supposed to go at top of html page.`

Comment: @Nick It can be at the top, but what was happening is the JS code was running before the HTML parser reached the form element. In other words the form element did not exist at the time the JS code `$('form').on('submit')` ran. Typically, you'll want to wrap your code in `$(document).ready` so the order of the code on the page doesn't matter. But in general, it is better to put JavaScript at the bottom of the page so it doesn't prevent the page from being parsed (if it takes longer to load).

Comment: When a script needs elements to work on, these elements have to exist (be parsed by DOM) when the script is parsed. That is a good practice to put those at page top, but in this case, the  `$(document).ready()` is an event handler to "wait" for the DOM to be ready before the script execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createUser(username,password){
            $.ajax({
                url : "/php/Create_User.php",
                method : "POST",
                data : { username: username, password : password},
                dataType : "text",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },error:function(xhr,data){
                    console.log(data+xhr);
                }
            })
        }
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code  but you can try mine tho, by the way try to remove the **"method=post"** in the form tag.
Using console.log and watch the output in Chrome by pressing F12 and go to console tab

Comment: @Nick in the error function parameter change to `error:function((error)` and `console.log(error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown))`

Comment: jqXHR is not defined

Comment: @Nick my fault, it should be `console.log(error(textStatus, errorThrown))`